# How to specify a command that should be called by #'repeat?

Tags: commands

I want to create a command that, when you call it for the first time, it's executed normally, but when you repeat it with `C-x z`, some other command is executed and the original command is never called.

I tried defining it like that (I want `forward-line` to be called when repeating `foo`):

```
(defun foo ()
  (interactive)
  (message "foo")
  (setq this-command 'forward-line))
```

but `M-x foo` and then `C-x z` just displays "foo" twice and never calls `'forward-line`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the source code for `repeat` (<kbd>C-h k C-x z</kbd> and then click on the `repeat.el` link in the `*Help*` buffer), you will see that the command to be repeated is stored in the variable `last-repeatable-command`, which is taken from `real-this-command` (as per its doc).

Note the comment in the `repeat` function:

```
       ;; Beware: messing with `real-this-command' is *bad*, but we
       ;; need it so `last-repeatable-command' can be recognized
       ;; later (bug#12232).
```

I am not sure what you are doing is right.

E.g., in your specific case, <kbd>C-u 234 down</kbd> will repeat `next-line` 234 times.

Comment: Changing `this-command` to `last-repeatable-command` didn't work, but when I looked at the doc of the latter, it mentioned that the value of this variable is taken from `real-this-command`. I replaced `this-command` with `real-this-command` and it works exactly how I want. Thanks!

Comment: I know that it's kind of a hack, actually I solved it by splitting the main command into two functions and then calling one of them depending on the return value of `repeat-is-really-this-command`.